# What is the OS name and browser version for Windows NT 6.1 and Mozilla/4.0?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I currently see the following browser information from a user:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (  
  compatible;   
  MSIE 8.0;   
  Windows NT 6.1;   
  Trident/4.0;   
  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ;   
  SLCC2; 
  .NET CLR 2.0.50727; 
  .NET CLR 3.5.30729; 
  .NET CLR 3.0.30729; 
  Media Center PC 6.0; 
  MS-RTC LM 8
)
```

From the above, it looks like the user is using `Internet Explorer 8.0` with `MSIE 8.0`.  `Windows NT 6.1` means `Windows 7`.  How is that combination possible?  I thought Win7 only supports IE9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NT 6.1 = Windows 7 and IE8 = Internet Explorer 8 which is the default IE version in Windows 7. IE9 was shipped later.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.useragentstring.com/, enter that useragent string and click the analyze button. It will tell you everything about that useragent string with lots of links to external references.